# Why do I need to write "function(value) {return my_function(value);}" as a callback in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

totally new to JS so please forgive if this is mind-bogglingly obvious.

Suppose I want to filter a list of strings with a function f that maps string -> bool. This works:

```
filteredList = list.filter(function(x) { return f(x); })
```

This fails:

```
filteredList = list.filter(f)
```

Why???

Code example:

```
 ~/projects/node (master)$ node
> var items = ["node.js", "file.txt"]
undefined
> var regex = new RegExp('\\.js$')
undefined
> items.filter(regex.test)
TypeError: Method RegExp.prototype.test called on incompatible receiver undefined
    at test (native)
    at Array.filter (native)
    at repl:1:8
    at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:110:21)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:239:12)
    at Interface.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:202:10)
    at Interface._line (readline.js:531:8)
    at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:760:14)
    at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:99:10)
> items.filter(function(value) { return regex.test(value); } )
[ 'node.js' ]
>
```

Comment: If you just have `f`, then there is no difference. If you are calling a function as a method of an object, there might be.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You're passing a reference to the "test" function, but when it gets called the regular expression object won't be around. In other words, inside "test" the value of `this` will be `undefined`.

You can avoid that:

```
items.filter(regex.test.bind(regex))
```

The `.bind()` method will return a function that'll always run with the value of "regex" as `this`.

Comment: beat to the punch again!  :)

Answer (score 8):

The reason you often can't do this is that functions used as methods are not simply methods.  If you use them without invoking them as methods they are then divorced of their original context.  You can get around this with `Function.prototype.bind`:

```
items.filter(regex.test.bind(regex));
```

Answer (score 5):

As others have said, `this` is `undefined` when the function reference is called. I'd like to offer a non-reflexive, slightly verbose, alternative:

```
items.filter(RegExp.prototype.test.bind(/regex/g));
```